# On the use of word "similar"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I am thinking to express the meaning of "My perspective on the issue A is similar to Alexia's perspective on issue B" in other different ways. I have a few questions.

1. I wanted to use a structure like: "I have a similar perspective on issue A to Alexia's on issue B". How can I make this sentence grammatically correct?
2. Can I simplify my original sentence to "My perspective on issue A is similar to Alexia's one on issue B" or  "My perspective on issue A is similar to Alexia's on issue B".
3. If Alexia = me, meaning, I wanted to just say "My perspective on issue A is similar to my perspective on issue B". Can I use some kind of conjunction reduction here? For example, would "My perspective on issue A is similar to on issue B" correct? Would "My perspective on issue A is similar to issue B" be correct?
4. (EDITED) Along the same line, can I simplify the sentence "The perspective of the university is similar to the perspective of the government" in some way? Can I say "The perspective of the university is similar to the government" or "The perspective of the university is similar to that of the government"

I am generally confused about the use of the word similar and the resulting issues about whether I can delete any part for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the meaning. Everything is dependent on intended meaning.

> My perspective on purveyance is similar to Gardiner's perspective on wardship

is perfectly good English grammar. It is comparing two things **of the same kind,** namely an opinion about an issue in English history.

> My perspective on purveyance is similar to Gardiner's on wardship

is a perfect example of ellipsis. I have dropped the noun "perspective," but the possessive implies the missing noun.

> My perspective on purveyance is similar to Gardiner on wardship

is an error in my opinion. Descriptive grammarians may say that it is not a **grammatical** error because people frequently do say things like that. But it is liable to cause the reader at least temporary confusion because perspective on an issue is a completely different kind of thing from a human being: a perspective has no nose, no sense of smell, no sense of humor. There can be no meaningful similarity between an opinion and a person. The fact that people can figure out the intended meaning says more for their common sense than for the felicity of the phrasing.

You can of course say grammatically and understandably

> My view on purveyance is similar to my view on wardship

It is grammatical and understandable, but it is more concise and at least as clear to say

> My views on purveyance and wardship are similar.

Comment: Thanks! This perfectly answered bullet 2. Could you also please help me with 1,3&4? The reason that I care about them is that in many other cases --- I only gave a toy example in  the question ---  I do want to structure the sentence in those ways for various reasons (e.g., to make sure the subject of the sentence is not too long.) Thanks!

Comment: I am perplexed by this comment. I had hoped that my first three examples would address bullets 1 and 2. And that my second two examples would address bullet 3. As for bullet 4, you can simplify it to "The perspectives of the government and university on this issue are similar." What more would you like me to address?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry for the confusion. I guess in 1,3&4, I was specifically interested in how to use a sentence structure very close to what I proposed. For example in 4, the sentence you said indeed is definitely correct and nice, but if I use it for my particular setting, where there are more clauses following the word government, the subject will be super long. So that's why I am interested in having a sentence with a structure like "The perspective of the university is similar to the that of the government" so that I could have more clauses after "government".

Comment: OK. The university's perspective is similar to the government's, which is ...